# ORA-00904 Invalid Identifier. Query works in 12c but not in 11g

Tags: linq, oracle11g, oracle12c

I have a LINQ query, trying to execute it on oracle 11g.
The same query executes perfectly fine on 12c but it gives following error on 11g.

```
ORA-00904: "Extent1"."ID": invalid identifier

00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

*Cause:   
*Action:
```

Following is the generated SQL. Just showing the specific part of query which is giving error,

```
SELECT 
  "Extent1".ID,
  (
    SELECT "top".ADMIT_DATE
    FROM 
          ( 
            SELECT "Project7".ADMIT_DATE
              FROM ( SELECT "Extent7".ADMIT_DATE FROM SYS.Table2 "Extent7" WHERE "Extent1".ID = "Extent7".ID )"Project7"
              ORDER BY "Project7".ADMIT_DATE ASC
          )  "top"
    WHERE ( ROWNUM <= 1) AND ROWNUM <= 1
  ) 
AS C1 FROM SYS.Table1 "Extent1";
```

Can someone please explain what's causing the issue in 11g !! This query works fine on 12c.

UPDATE:
Here are the linq queries.
Above SQL is a part of SQL generated by these linq queries.

```
var query = from p in context.Person
            where p.Meetings.Any() &&
            p.Vitals.Any(v => v.WT.HasValue && v.WT >= 20 && v.WT <= 300) &&
            p.Detentions.Any(d => ((d.DX_TYPE != null && d.DX_TYPE == "09") || (d.DX_TYPE == null && "09" == null)) && d.DX.StartsWith("V") && d.DX != null) &&
            p.Meetings.Any(meet => meet.Detentions.Any(d => ((d.DX_TYPE != null && d.DX_TYPE == "09") || (d.DX_TYPE == null && "09" == null)) && d.DX.StartsWith("250") && d.DX != null))
            select new
            {
                p.HISPANIC,
                p.RACE,
                StudentID = p.PersonID,
                AdmissionOn = p.Meetings.OrderBy(meet => meet.ADMIT_DATE).Select(meet => meet.ADMIT_DATE).FirstOrDefault(),
                AdmissionYear = p.Meetings.OrderBy(meet => meet.ADMIT_DATE).Select(meet => meet.ADMIT_DATE).FirstOrDefault().Year,
                AdmissionMonth = p.Meetings.OrderBy(meet => meet.ADMIT_DATE).Select(meet => meet.ADMIT_DATE).FirstOrDefault().Month
            };

var g = query.GroupBy(k => new { Hispanic = k.HISPANIC, Race = k.RACE, AdmissionYear = k.AdmissionYear })
            .Select(k => new { Hispanic = k.Key.Hispanic, Race = k.Key.Race, AdmissionYear = k.Key.AdmissionYear, Persons = k.Count() }).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm surprised it works in 12.1.  Normally, you can't reference an identifier more than one layer deep.  So "Extent1" would be a valid identifier in your `SELECT "top".ADMIT_DATE` inline select but not in the inline view that is nested one layer deeper.  Perhaps 12.1 has relaxed that requirement though I don't recall reading anything that indicated that was a intentional change.  Are you really looking for that explanation, though, or for a query that works in both versions?  Are your tables really in the `sys` schema?  That would be highly inadvisable.

Comment: Actually this thing is working correctly in 12c !! I am not looking for explanation specifically, all I am looking for is a working solution for this. I am suppose to write this in linq, and above is just a generated SQL. I am messing my head with the linq query.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to include the LINQ query that generates that output.

Comment: @AlexPoole added LINQ queries.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that Oracle 11g doesn't support referencing identifiers more than one query deep. SQL Server (created by Microsoft) does support this, which is why your LINQ is working fine, but the Oracle server doesn't like the SQL.

It is, essentially, a bug in oracle provider tools, which are not translating your LINQ into valid SQL for version 11g.